# Conics Confusion

Tags: conic-sections

I'm currently reading through a document about the ellipse. I've attached the provided image and working out.

[image]

From here, it is easy enough to show that $|OP|\sin\gamma=|FP|\sin\alpha$ using say the Sine Rule.

However, they follow through with

[image]

I understand how they got the first two lines using the polar equation of the ellipse (with respect to the focus) $r=FP=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos\theta}$.

Where I have issue is with the "Summing the squares". I cannot see how they managed to get rid of all the $\alpha$ and have everything in terms of $\gamma$.

Is there some sort of identity that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the first equation by $\sqrt{1-e^2}$:
$$
\begin{align}
|OP|\frac{\sin{\gamma}}{\sqrt{1-e^2}}&=|OQ|\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin(\alpha)}{1+e\cos(\alpha)}\tag{1}\\
|OP|\cos(\gamma)&=|OQ|\frac{e+\cos(\alpha)}{1+e\cos(\alpha)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
then add the squares of $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$
|OP|^2\left(\frac{\sin^2(\gamma)}{1-e^2}+\cos^2(\gamma)\right)=|OQ|^2\tag{3}
$$